# select query without giving space in-between *(star) symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, select-query

```
select*from tablename -- without spaces in-between the star symbol

select * from tablename -- Applied spaces in-between the star symbol
```

Both queries are working in my **Sql-Server-2016** query window. What is the difference and which situation we need to use this? and why `Sql server` accept this?

Comment: first `*` is not star symbol it is meta character.

Comment: @YogeshSharma. thanks mate. then?

Comment: Short answer : it is the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference. As with many programming languages, T-SQL is *parsed* from input composed of strings. During parsing, many different types of "things" may be pulled from the text, such as KEYWORDs (such as `select` and `from`) and ASTERISK (`*`).

It's simply the fact that there is no need for whitespace here since an asterisk character cannot be part of any KEYWORD or unescaped IDENTIFIER (such as a column or table name)<sup>1</sup>, and so there's no parsing ambiguity that whitespace would be required to help resolve.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's not uncommon (cannot speak for T-SQL specifically) that the parser uses a single pattern just for IDENTIFIERs and a later step actually distinguishes IDENTIFIERs that are in a specifically enumerated list are in fact  KEYWORDs.

Comment: Also, We can write SQL queries without space using comments `select/**/*/**/from/**/tablename`

Comment: >>>It's simply the fact that there is no need for whitespace here since an asterisk character cannot be part of any KEYWORD or unescaped IDENTIFIER<<< Why cannot we write select8 ? 8 cannot be a part of keyword and any identifier, if it starts with digit, should be quoted

Comment: +1 but  What about this `Select Top 1*from tableName`? this is also works as `Select Top 1 * from tableName` @damien

Comment: @sepupic - `select8` would be a perfectly "good" name for an IDENTIFIER. Depending on how the T-SQL parser is implemented, it may have a single pattern for IDENTIFIER which all identifiers and keywords are matched by and only latter distinguishes between them.

Comment: @sepupic - E.g. `create procedure select8
as
print 'Hello'
go
select8` prints `Hello` as expected.